# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection

Tags: java, jenkins, noclassdeffounderror

I am having this problem when trying to build my project with Jenkins:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection
at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Unix.get(ProcessTree.java:506)
at hudson.util.ProcessTree.killAll(ProcessTree.java:144)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.destroy(Proc.java:380)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.join(Proc.java:353)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.join(CommandInterpreter.java:155)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:109)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
```

I have tried to downgrade from JAVA JDK 1.8 to 1.7 but still not resolving the problem.

This is a JavaScript project, the test are passing but build failed because of that error.

Could you help me?

Comment: Which is the Jenkins version?

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, version 2.46.1

Comment: can you check if it's related to -
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21341

please verify the versions

Comment: Thanks for helping, I have tried to downgrade, still not working

Comment: This looks like a known Jenkins bug : issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46523, are u in java 9 for running Jenkins ?

Answer (score 1):

We fixed it by reducing jenkins stdout/stderr output. Just redirect called commands' output to files and try again.

It is just a workaround until Jenkins team fix it but it works pretty well for us.