# Running jenkins job getting error -> FATAL: Could not initialize class hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection

Tags: java, jenkins

Good evening,

I have been pulling my hair with that error, not able to get any solution over the internet.

Just trying to build my Javascript project with Jenkins. my test are written with Jasmine framework and are all passing but if fails because of that error:

```
FATAL: Could not initialize class hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection
at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Unix.get(ProcessTree.java:506)
at hudson.util.ProcessTree.killAll(ProcessTree.java:144)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.destroy(Proc.java:380)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.join(Proc.java:353)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.join(CommandInterpreter.java:155)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:109)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
```

Already tried to downgrade Java JDK from 1.8 to 1.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726875/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-hudson-util-processtr)

Comment: This looks like a known Jenkins bug : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46523, are u in java 9 for running Jenkins ?